# A cartoon about two men in top hats chasing after a girl in distress

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show, animation

I remember watching a movie on Cartoon Network as a child with two men in top hats chasing after a girl in these very colorful, very vivid scenes. The only characters are the two men in top hats, the girl, and the villain who is kidnapping her (though I remember nothing about him). One scene I remember is the villain carrying the girl over his shoulder crossing a short bridge with the two men in pursuit.

The men in top hats were an anachronistic version of [ATLAS and P-body from Portal 2](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/ATLAS_and_P-body), one being tall and skinny, the other short and plump. The two men were definitely something out of the late 19th, early 20th century.

Oh, there was no speaking in the movie, to my recollection, so it was kind of like a very colorful, silent movie.

The animation was very similar to [Foster's Home for Imaginary Friends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foster%27s_Home_for_Imaginary_Friends), but it was crisper, very detailed, except somewhat [steampunk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steampunk). Basically, the art style is very hallucinogenic. If I were to estimate when I watched it, I would guess around 2000.

Comment: Currently it holds very less details. Can you specify anything else when did you watched it or any other story plot or character.

Comment: I added a few more details.

Comment: I added a comparison to the two men and an estimated era of time that the movie takes place in.

Comment: Just for clarification... These were animated humans, right? No chance of them being animated cats?

Comment: I'm almost positive they were two men in top hats. Why? What movie are you thinking of?

Comment: Are you sure it was a movie? not some kind of series? And can u tell me more about how that girl looked like? :)

Comment: I believe that she had brown hair.

Comment: The description of the two men sound like they could be Laurel & Hardy.. Although it's probably not what you're looking for, but there used to be a few animated series about them.

Comment: I remember The New Scooby-Doo Movies episode with them! Any lead is a good lead, I'll look into it.

Comment: I think it would be a couple if characters called Mutt and Jeff...maybe googling those names will turn up more info.

Comment: Also a similar couple! I couldn't, however, find a cartoon of them that looks to have been made past 2000.

Comment: It is also worth noting that no one spoke in this movie. It was like a colorful silent movie.

Answer (score 4):

Your description reminded me of The Perils of Penelope Pitstop, by Hanna Barbera. Not sure though, as there were more than two men with hats, but have a [look here](http://www.hotink.com/wacky/pitstop/).

(Funny, because I was thinking of this cartoon just the other day...)

Comment: Oh wow, I actually remember this cartoon! Sadly it's too old to be the one I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be "Sherlock Holmes in the 22nd Century".  See if this pic rings a bell:

[image]

Comment: The art style was very, very colorful. Kind of like Foster's Home for Imaginary Friends.

Comment: What is up with her elbow interior?

Answer (score 2):

I think you were looking for Laurel and Hardy (animated series), It was a cartoon based on Stan Laurel and Oliver Hardy's comedic acts by the animation studio Hanna-Barbera from Hal Roach.

PS: Sorry, probably not the one since this one is old.

Comment: Good guess and I loved them on Scooby-Doo, but you're right it's too old.